# ayuda Tengo un problema en haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Este es mi codigo    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
!!!5
    %html{class:"no-js", lang:"es"}
      %head
        %meta{charset:"utf-8"}
        %title La mejor comida.
        %meta{name:"description", content:"Come rico en el mejor restaurante de la ciudad, servicio de primera."}
        %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/normalize.css"}
        %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/style.css"}
        %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
        %script{src:"js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"}
      %body
      ="<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
            %p{class:"browserupgrade"}
            Estas usando un navegador 
            %strong desactualizado. 
            Por favor 
            %a{href:"http://browsehappy.com/"}
            actualiza tu navegador 
            para una mejor experiencia.
        ="<![endif]-->"
        .video-container 
            %video{autoplay:true,loop:true,width:"1280",height:"720"}
                /Cambiar Videos, Poner el poster                      
                %source{src:"/videos/mp4/cambiar.mp4",type:"video/mp4"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error indica que has dado más espacios/tabs de los que deberías, en este caso 3 niveles; recuerda que debes seguir la indentación adecuada, es decir, un nivel en cada sección; por ejemplo:

```
!!!5
    %html{class:"no-js", lang:"es"}
      %head
        %meta{charset:"utf-8"}
        %title La mejor comida.
        %meta{name:"description", content:"Come rico en el mejor restaurante de la ciudad, servicio de primera."}
        %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/normalize.css"}
        %link{rel:"stylesheet", href:"css/style.css"}
        %meta{name:"viewport", content:"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
        %script{src:"js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"}
      %body
      ="<!--[if lt IE 9]>"
        %p{class:"browserupgrade"}
        Estas usando un navegador 
        %strong desactualizado. 
        Por favor 
        %a{href:"http://browsehappy.com/"}
        actualiza tu navegador 
        para una mejor experiencia.
      ="<![endif]-->"
        .video-container 
          %video{autoplay:true,loop:true,width:"1280",height:"720"}
            /Cambiar Videos, Poner el poster                      
            %source{src:"/videos/mp4/cambiar.mp4",type:"video/mp4"}
```